# Given these premises, could they reach this conclusion?

Tags: logic

p v q

q -> (-r -> s)

-p -> r

could those premises reach the conclusion of s ??

I've skimmed through the surface of inference logic, and my answer is no, because i keep finding roadblock in form of -q -> s, where the conclusion only wants s and s alone, no?

Answer (score 1):

First write

$$q \to (\neg r \to s) \equiv q \to (\neg \neg r \lor s )\equiv q \to (r \lor s) \equiv \neg q \lor r \lor s$$

And also write $$\neg p \to r \equiv p \lor r$$

Now we have premises

$$1: p \lor q$$ $$2: \neg q \lor r \lor  s$$ $$3: p \lor r$$

Well, let $p = 1, q = 0, r = 0, s=0$. Then all three premises are true, while $s$ is false. So you cannot conclude $s$ is true.